# How can i get the timestamp and lock the failed login form?

Tags: ms-access, authentication, ms-access-2013

As the title stated, can anyone help me about my form login on Access 2013.
I just want to get timestamp updated on my username table (datetype datetime) for each successfull login on each userid. Another problem is i want to lock the user login form for each 3 times failed login.

```
Private Sub CmdLogin_Click()

If IsNull(Me.cboNama) Or Me.cboNama = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill your username first!", vbOKOnly, "Input Username"
    Me.cboNama.SetFocus
     Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtPword) Or Me.txtPword = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill your password!", vbOKOnly, "Input Password"
    Me.txtPword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.txtPword.Value = DLookup("Password", "Ms_UserID", "[Password]='" &                 Me.txtPword.Value & "'") Then
    MyUserID = Me.cboNama.Value
    MsgBox "Login Success", vbOKOnly, "Message"
    'Me.Last_Login = DateTime()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Frm_Login", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Ms_Userid"

    Else
    MsgBox "Wrong Username/Password!  Please specify your caps lock, Boss..", vbCritical, "Error Message"
    Me.txtPword.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql-statement would be essentially:

```
"UPDATE username SET thestamp = NOW() WHERE userid = " & frms!yourForm!txtUserID
```

You can use `DoCmd.RunSql` to run this sql:

```
DoCmd.RunSql "the sql statement"
```

or `CurrentDb.Execute`.

At the top of the Form's Module you can create a Private variable to count the number of attempts:

```
Private counter As Integer
```

It will default to 0. Then clicking a button can increase it with `counter = counter + 1`.

This is not secure or foolproof at all. The user could simple close and re-open the form. You could store the counter in a table but, again, this can be easily over-written.

**Added** `timestamp` is a reserved word in Access and needs to be enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: I tried you suggestion above... but still i have an error when i pressed those ok/login button...The error is "Run Time Error 424" Object required ... I write down the code i typed in VBA Access 2013 below, please take a look..many thanks!

Comment: DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Ms_Userid SET timestamp = Now() where UserID=" & frms!Frm_Login!cboNama & ";"

Comment: If it's a combobox then you'll need `cboNama.Column(0)` for the first column. If it's text then this value needs to be surrounded in apostrophes.

Comment: Hi Andy G, today i do modification on my Login Button, and here is the final result.. It still has error which says that "Enter parameter value" and it's written that Msuserid.timestamp, There is a textbox "OK" "Cancel" Button...

Answer (score 0):

This is my latest modification for Click Button VBA Code, please take a look since there is still an error (pop up window appears and it says "Enter parameter value : Ms_Userid.timestamp" Should i enter i manually ? Because i'm already using = NOW() function.

Many thanks.!

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim SQL As String

'Check mandatory fields
If IsNull(Me.cboNama.Value) Or Me.cboNama.Value = "" Then
   MsgBox "User ID is required.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
   Me.cboNama.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtPword.Value) Or Me.txtPword.Value = "" Then
   MsgBox "Password is required.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
   Me.txtPword.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If





SQL = "UPDATE Ms_Userid " & _
          "SET Ms_Userid.timestamp = Now()" & _
          "WHERE Ms_Userid.UserID = '&frms!Frm_Login!cboNama&'"





'Compare input password and database password
If Me.cboNama.Value <> "" Then
   If Me.txtPword.Value = DLookup("Password", "Ms_UserID", "[Password]='" & Me.txtPword.Value & "'") Then
      'MyUserID = Me.cboNama.Value
      'DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Ms_Userid SET timestamp = Now() where UserID='" & frms!Frm_Login!cboNama & "';"
      DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
      'Close Login Page
      MsgBox "Login Success", vbOKOnly, "Message"
      DoCmd.Close acForm, "Frm_Login", acSaveNo
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Ms_Userid"
   Else
      MsgBox "Invalid Password. Try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
      Me.txtPword.SetFocus
   End If
End If

'If user enters incorrect password 3 times
intLoginAttempts = intLoginAttempts + 1
If intLoginAttempts = 3 Then
   MsgBox "You do not have access to the database. Please contact system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
   Application.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to break out the form-value from the quoted string: `" WHERE Ms_Userid.UserID = '" & frms!Frm_Login!cboNama & "'"` and there should be a space before WHERE. Do you have a field named `timestamp`?

Comment: I've also added to my answer. But it is also `forms` not `frms`.

Comment: Well about the timestamp field, it's may mistake i'm sorry... The field name should be the same as in the table, "Last_Login" which has datatype of "Date"

Comment: I do modification again on "break down quoted string" you told me about.. and here it is : SQL = "UPDATE Ms_Userid " & _
          "SET Ms_Userid.Last_Login = Now()" & _
          " WHERE Ms_Userid.UserID = '" & frms!Frm_Login!cboNama "'" But it is still has an error "variable not defined"